# How to use a dictionary inside a definition

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to use a definition to import onto my main function and I have a dictionary inside it. How can I use it? (Google didn't help)

How can I use the dictionary inside the function?

data_storage.ipynb:

```
def storage():
    dictionary = {
        'server_price' : 100,
        'server_rack' : 30, 
        'conections' : 50
    }
```

Also if I try to use this dictionary in another function would it work? This is a separate question to the first.

calculate_final.ipynb:

```
def calteam(number_of_servers):
    number_of_servers * (1/5)
def price_team({team}):
      calteam * 200
def calculate_total( {price_team}, servers, server_racks, conections,):
    server_total = servers * dictionary[server_price]
    {price_team} + server_total + server_racks + conections
```

eventualy I am going to combine these into one by importing the functions

Comment: I am currently active if y'all need any more info 7:07 CST

Comment: ```dictionary``` won't be available in ```calculate_total()``` because ```dictionary``` in ```storage()``` is local to that function unless you either make it a global variable or you  ```return dictionary``` in ```storage()``` and have ```calculate_total``` do something like ```servers * storage()[server_price]```.  That's the general concept.

Comment: If I return the dictionary in storage() would I be able to keep these two separate?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need your dictionary to be defined inside that function? Why not just define it outside like you'd define any other variable? Or, as you've asked in comments elsewhere, define it in a separate module and import that module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about making the dictionary global and use it in the functions or call from different .py file

```
# dict_file.py
DICTIONARY = {
    'server_price' : 100,
    'server_rack' : 30, 
    'conections' : 50
}

# main.py
import dict_file

def storage():
    dict_file.DICTIONARY
    
def calteam(number_of_servers):
    number_of_servers * (1/5)
    
def price_team({team}):
      calteam * 200
def calculate_total( {price_team}, servers, server_racks, conections,):
    server_total = servers * dict_file.DICTIONARY[server_price]
    {price_team} + server_total + server_racks + conections
```

Comment: That works, but can keep them separate and import them onto my main code later?

Comment: yes, you can keep in separate .py file and call from there, or use it as global

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the dictionary because it is defined in the function as a local variable. If you can modify the function, you should make dictionary a parameter instead:

```py
dictionary = {
    'server_price' : 100,
    'server_rack' : 30, 
    'conections' : 50
}

def storage(dictionary):
    # function logic
```

And the dictionary can be accessed in the global scope in the notebook, or in a separate file as well, as long as the first file is imported

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use a class with `__call__` method defined

```py
class Foo:
   data_dict = ...
   @classmethod
   def __call__(cls, args):
       ....
```

Then you can use the class as follows:

```py
x = Foo(args)
y = Foo.dict[...]
```